# Changing a Javascript variable in objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using this code (in my .m file) to pass a variable into a bundled javascript file.

```
[animalDesciption stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var myIDcounterVariable = '1'"];
```

I set this up and it works great to change the value of a UILabel by pushing a  UIButton:

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender {
number++;
[currentNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];

}
```

How can I make the button change the value of the JavaScript variable like I'm doing with the Label?

Pardon my stumbling words! I'm very new to this kind of programming...

Please tell me if I need to give more info.

Comment: What am I doing wrong, why did I get downvoted? I am more than willing to be told why I shouldn't ask a question, or that there is a better way to do it. I've spent all afternoon trying to figure out how to do this, and posting this comment is last-resort.

Comment: I think it's a little unclear what your exact problem is. You seem to have all the pieces in your code above, but I can't tell what the problem is in putting them together, and you didn't say what you've tried.

Comment: Ok, basically I could get the first block of code to do what I wanted it to do by manually changing the '1' to '2' (or '3' or '4') and re building the app and running it.

Comment: So what my current code does, is scroll my UIWebView to the first ('1') instance of an anchor in the html. By changing the '1' to another number the page will scroll to the second or third anchor.

The reason that I did the label was to see if i could increment a value by clicking the button, it worked great! The breakdown was that I don't know how to get my incremented value into the place if the '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding this JavaScript function to my UIWebView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max = 100;

function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/hl/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#hl",""));
        (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#hl" + String(newh-1); 
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "hl1";        
    }
}

</script>
```

Then sending this JavaScript call with my IBAction like this:

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    [animalDesciption stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"goToNext()"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you need?

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    number++;

    // You want Javascript like this to run:
    //     myIDCounterVariable = '1'
    // but with the current value of 'number' in it.

    // Construct the string:
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myIDCounterVariable = '%d'", number];

    // and run it
    [animalDesciption stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, but it doesn't do anything for me! I'm thinking that it might be because the javascript function requires that the variable be set when the page loads, and when the variable changes later it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sounds plausible. You probably want your JS to have a function like "scrollToAnchorWithIndex()". Then have the Obj-C code construct the JS string like "scrollToAnchorWithIndex(%d)" and evaluate it.

Comment: Yes that is similar to what I did, I just did the incrementing with JavaScript. On second thought, it might be cleaner to increment in Obj-C like your suggesting... I'll go ahead and post my current configuration.